# my website is not working as responsive on some browsers of mobile?

Tags: html, responsive-design, web

i have a website

```
www.harryenglishclub.com
```

it is working fine on computer and also showing responsive when change to mobile view but one mobile it working fine in operamini but not in google chrome . and

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

is already added to my header.

Comment: I just ran an audit on your site, and it is not showing you have `<meta name="viewport">`  tag on your homepage, with width or initial scale. My suggestion would be to create metaHeader that is just included on every page.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I see when I inspect the source code of www.harryenglishclub.com

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <title>www.harryenglishclub.com</title> 
</head>
<frameset rows="100%,*" border="0">
  <frame src="http://www.chamanvatikagurukul.in/hec" frameborder="0" />
  <frame frameborder="0" noresize />
</frameset>

<!-- pageok -->
<!-- 10 -->
<!-- -->
</html>
```

You are pulling in an external site and placing it in a `<frameset>`.

Try adding a viewport meta tag in the head of your parent document. It seems to work for me in inspector but I can't confirm for sure on a mobile device.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>www.harryenglishclub.com</title> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<frameset rows="100%,*" border="0">
  <frame src="http://www.chamanvatikagurukul.in/hec" frameborder="0" />
  <frame frameborder="0" noresize />
</frameset>

<!-- pageok -->
<!-- 10 -->
<!-- -->
</html>
```

Good luck!